# Class methods - which one to use and when?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

There seems to be two different way to define a method within a class.

```
class Foo {
    handleClick = e => {
        // handle click
    }
    // and
    handleHover(e) {
        // handle hover
    }
}
```

My question is what is the difference between the two?

When transpiled, they give decidedly different results:

```
var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Foo = function () {
    function Foo() {
        _classCallCheck(this, Foo);

        this.handleClick = function (e) {}
        // handle click

        // and
        ;
    }

    _createClass(Foo, [{
        key: "handleHover",
        value: function handleHover(e) {
            // handle hover
        }
    }]);

    return Foo;
}();
```

But I can't seem to discern what the differences are. Is it a binding issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's just the difference between an arrow function and a function expression. The method syntax is just syntactic sugar for function expressions.

Comment: I reopened the question since the duplicate doesn't really apply here. Note that your code is not valid ES6. It uses a feature proposal for a future version of ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    handleClick = e => {
        // handle click
    }
}
```

is not ES6. [It's a proposal for a future version of ES](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/).

The equivalent ES5 code to your example would be

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.handleClick = e => {
            // handle click
        }
    }
    // and
    handleHover(e) {
        // handle hover
    }
}
```

and the equivalent ES6 code to your example would be

```
function Foo() {
  this.handleClick = function(e) {
      // handle click
  }.bind(this);
}

Foo.prototype.handleHover = function(e) {
    // handle hover
}
```

So basically `handleClick` is autobound to the instance, which can be useful for event handlers, but it comes at the cost of creating a new function for every instance.

For more information see

- [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/218196)
- [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: Oh interesting. I hadn't noticed that I had ticked `stage-2` in my Babel REPL. Unticking it threw a syntax error, which makes sense. So it essentially "autobinds" but creates a new function whenever the `new` is invoked. Makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: Note that "autobinding" is a consequence of using an arrow function, not using a "class field". I.e. `handleClick = function(){}` would define the function inside the constructor, but you wouldn't get autobinding.